# Drawing a plane slicing a cylinder through its axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a cylinder with a plane that slices it through its vertical axis. The plane should have a width such that the whole section of the cylinder is sliced. It should also be taller than the cylinder. I managed to do this:

[image]

The problem is that I'm not being able to show that the plane is actually wider than the cylinder. If I increase the width by a large amount, then this happens:

[image]

So there is no way to understand what the drawing is trying to show. Is there any way to do this aesthetically? I'm not looking for this specific cylinder or this specific plane, the design can be whatever you think is better. I just need a cylinder sliced by a plane, with the latter being taller and wider than the former.

The code to generate the pictures above can be found below:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,backgrounds,patterns}

\begin{document}
\def\R{3}
\def\w{10}
\def\hc{6}
\def\hp{9}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-\hc/2]
        \draw[dashed] (\tdplotmainphi:\R) arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:\R);
        \draw[thick] (\tdplotmainphi:\R) coordinate (BR) arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180:\R)
        coordinate (BL);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-\hp/2]
        \draw[thick] (0:\w) coordinate (PS1) -- (180:\w) coordinate (PS2);
        \coordinate (A) at (0:\R);
        \coordinate (B) at (180:\R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\hp/2]
        \draw[thick] (0:\w) coordinate (PI1) -- (180:\w) coordinate (PI2);
        \coordinate (A') at (0:\R);
        \coordinate (B') at (180:\R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\hc/2]
        \draw[thick] (0,0) coordinate (O') circle[radius=\R];
        \path[pattern=north east lines] (PS1) -- (PS2) -- (PI2) -- (PI1) -- cycle;
        \draw (BR) -- (\tdplotmainphi:\R) (BL) -- (\tdplotmainphi-180:\R);
        \draw[thick] (PS1) -- (PI1);
        \draw[thick] (PS2) -- (PI2);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another problem is the perspective on the cylinder and the plane do not match.  The distance from the bottom or top of the plane (parallelogram) and the intersections with the cylinder should be constant.  Of course, using tikz-3dplot will take care of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing one can do is to fill the cylinder and draw it in four stretches and the parts that are behind the plane have to be drawn first. BTW, `tikz-3dplot` loads the `3d` and `calc` libraries.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=3;w=20;hc=6;hp=9;},
    fill opacity=0.7]
    \path[smooth,left color=gray,right color=gray,middle color=gray!50!black]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:180] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180:\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
    % stretch on the right behind the plane
    \path[smooth,left color=gray,right color=gray!60]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:0] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=0:\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
    % plane 
    \path[pattern=north east lines] (-w/2,0,-hp/2) 
        -- (w/2,0,-hp/2) -- (w/2,0,hp/2) -- (-w/2,0,hp/2) -- cycle; 
    % cylinder part on the back in front of the plane   
    \path[smooth,left color=gray!50!black,right color=gray]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180+\tdplotmainphi:180] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180:180+\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
    % cylinder part on the front in front of the plane  
    \path[smooth,left color=gray,right color=gray,middle color=gray!20]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180+\tdplotmainphi:360] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=360:180+\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, one can change the view angles and the style of the plane.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=3;w=12;hc=6;hp=9;},
    fill opacity=0.6]
    \path[smooth,left color=gray,right color=gray,middle color=gray!50!black]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:180] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180:\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
    % stretch on the right behind the plane
    \path[smooth,left color=gray,right color=gray!60]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=\tdplotmainphi:0] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=0:\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
    % plane 
    \path[fill=blue!30] (-w/2,0,-hp/2) 
        -- (w/2,0,-hp/2) -- (w/2,0,hp/2) -- (-w/2,0,hp/2) -- cycle; 
    % cylinder part on the back in front of the plane   
    \path[smooth,left color=gray!50!black,right color=gray]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180+\tdplotmainphi:180] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180:180+\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
    % cylinder part on the front in front of the plane  
    \path[smooth,left color=gray,right color=gray,middle color=gray!20]
     plot[variable=\t,domain=180+\tdplotmainphi:360] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},-hc/2) -- 
     plot[variable=\t,domain=360:180+\tdplotmainphi] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{R*sin(\t)},hc/2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea, I think it can be clearer that way. I'm not so sure about it being aesthetically appealing though. Wouldn't it be better to paint the plane with a solid color instead of using dashed lines? And maybe changing the perspective as well... I'll try those changes on my own, but I'm writing them here just in case you want to edit the answer. Remember that the design I proposed was arbitrary, the cylinder could be orange with puppies drawn on its surface and I wouldn't mind!

Comment: @Tendero I just copied the pattern from your code. I personally would not use the pattern, but as far as the pattern and view angles are concerned I just tried to follow your code. Ironically, when trying this out I changed the view angles to see if that looks good in principle.

Comment: That's perfect. I thought the pattern would be good to emphasize the fact that the surface is a plane, and that it's not a box (namely, that it doesn't have depth), but I don't think it worked as planned...